# How to save complete inspect output in R's tm package instead of sample matrix of size 10 * 10?

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

```
# My TermDocumentMatrix (TDM)
Nepal.tdm

# Structure of my TDM
str(Nepal.tdm)

# My locality vector
localities

# Structure of my locality vector
str(localities)
#chr [1:344] "kalyan" "surkhet" "chhinchu" "harre" "pyuthan" "thapdada" "khola" ...

# inspecting matching localities in my TDM
locality.matches <- inspect(Nepal.tdm[localities[localities %in% Terms(Nepal.tdm)], ])    

# I have tried following things but without success because the output is always 10 * 10 sample matrix when I want complete matrix of 200 * 92
as.data.frame(as.matrix(inspect(Nepal.tdm[localities[localities %in% Terms(Nepal.tdm)], ])))

capture.output(out <- data.frame(inspect(Nepal.tdm[localities[localities %in% Terms(Nepal.tdm)], ])))
```

Comment: can you make a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

Since tm v.0.7 inspect.TermDocumentMatrix() displays a sample instead of the full matrix. The full dense representation is available via as.matrix().

```
# This will give you the entire matrix, from here you can filter it as you want
as.matrix(Nepal.tdm)
```